# H2 DB version that is compatible with Apache Ignite 2.16

Tags: h2, ignite

I am trying Ignite 2.16. However, after configuring ignite-indexing the startup shows exception as '**java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/h2/value/ValueByte .....**".

Seems to me like a h2 version compatibility issue. the default h2 version that is automatically pulled in by ignite-indexing is h2-2.2.224.jar. I think the Ignite need a lower version of h2 library which has org.h2.value.ValueByte class in it.

Could anyone suggest which is the right/compatible h2 library version that I need to force into the gradle?

Comment: With Maven I frequently look at my dependency hierarchy when I have issues like this to see if there is a conflict between my dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Version [1.4.197](https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/f32480505f0b5a827b760789bc724008e68a6f3e/parent/pom.xml#L93). It's unlikely that one of Ignite's modules is pulling in the wrong version. Chances are, it's something like Spring.